# Python PriorityQueue gets only part of tuple

Tags: python, priority-queue

I'm having issues with priority queue in Python. I put in a tuple and when I iterate over it I get the tuple iterated over. What I want and expected to happen is the get() function would just return the whole tuple instead of just the first value of the first tuple.

Adding to queue:

```
await priority_queue.put((3, 'Value1', 'Value2'))
```

Iteration of queue:

```
for i in await priority_queue.get():
    print(i)
```

Result I get:

```
> 3
> 'Value1'
> 'Value2'
```

Result I want:

```
> (3, 'Value1', 'Value2')
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue)

> The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry is the one returned by sorted(list(entries))[0]). A typical pattern for entries is a tuple in the form: (priority_number, data).

Which makes me think something is wrong, though I don't completely understand what is meant here besides that it gets sorted.

Comment: you are thinking in wrong way `print(priority_queue.get())` this will print what you want. code you have written is iterating over the tuple you have inserted not priority queue

Comment: @deadshot ah yes, this was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was how I was thinking about queues. (Thanks to @deadshot)

```
print(priority_queue.get())
```

Works and there is no iteration if you just want the first object in queue.

```
while not priority_queue.empty():
    print(await priority_queue.get())
```

Is a good way to iterate over each object by itself. (Also allows for better looping elsewhere)